# Showing that $T(x)\geq{}x$ for a distance-preserving transformation $T$

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, transformation, isometry

> For a metric $d$ defined as $d(x,y)=|y-x|$ on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and a distance-preserving transformation mapping $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},d)$ to itself, we are asked to show that $T(x)\geq{}x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. And to show that equality only holds when $T$ is an isometry.

I've just started a course in Euclidean geometry and I've been stuck on this question for a couple hours, I know that for a distance-preserving transformation it holds that $d(x,y)=d(T(x),T(y))$ thus $|y-x|=|T(y)-T(x)|$ but I don't see how then the inequality arises, and why is it an equality when $T$ is bijective. Appreciate any help,

Edit: Due to an inconsistency remark, am making clear that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ here is the set of all positive integers, "distance-preserving" as $d(x,y)=d(T(x),T(y))$ for a transformation $T$ and an isometry as a transformation that is both bijective and distance-preserving.

Comment: 3 comments.  (1) is it $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, or did you mean $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (2) your definition of distance preserving is the same as isometry (3) in the question you say "equality holds when T is an isometry", but in your commentary you say "when T is bijective", so there is an inconsistency somewhere you should fix

Comment: @NazimJ I apologize for any incosistency, I mean $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, the set of all the positive real values, with distance-preserving I meant a transformation with the property $d(x,y)=d(T(x),T(y))$, regardless of it had any other behaviour. And with isometry I meant a transformation that is both bijective and distance-preserving, so since we already had the latter, I only mentioned the prior.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be such that $|T(x)-T(y)|=|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Work out the following facts:

1. $T$ is injective.
2. $T$ is continuous and, hence, monotonic.
3. $T$ is differentiable with $T^{\prime}=\pm1$.
4. There is a $b\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ such that $T(x)=x+b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

The claim then follows. These steps all follow from the definitions involved and properties of $T$. If you have trouble with any of the steps, feel free to ask.

Comment: Am sorry but I still can't link those facts to the claim, I see that if such a $b\in\mathbb{R}_{<0}$ exists that then $T(x)\geq{}x$ but I don't see how I can eliminate the y-term in the equality, could you please elaborate? Thank you

Comment: Which "y-term" are you referring to? No elimination is taking place as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @afreshnoob given the 4th claim, we have one of your quesitons easily, since $T(x)=x+b \geq x$.  Now if $T$ is bijective, it is surjective. Assume $b>0$.  Then for any $y<b$, there is *not* an $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $T(x)=y$.  So $T$ isn't surjective, hence $b$ must be $0$.  Hence $T(x)=x+0=x$ in case of bijective